# How do I share an image + text via WhatsApp?

Tags: ios, swift, share, whatsapp, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to share an image + text via WhatsApp.

Here is my code:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [imageNmae, "Share text"], applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self 

activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivity.ActivityType.airDrop]

activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems:[Any]?, error: Error?) in
    self.shareMainView.isHidden = true
}
if let viewController = UIApplication.topMostViewController {
    viewController.present(activityViewController, animated: true) {
        // self.shareMainView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

I can see some other apps sharing a URL and it's showing both an image and text. Even Android is able to share. But if execute the above code, I can only share text and not an image.

Comment: Does imageName reference is a String or UIImage in activityItems array?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You can send a text or an image. If you send an image the user will be prompted to write something if desired. I don't think you can choose what will be written.

Answer (score 1):

Share URL of the image along with your text.
WhatsApp will create preview from the link, and make it appear like image + text.

There is no real way of sending image + text on WhatsApp (in Nov 2021)